# How do I copy a woocommerce application from live server to localhost

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I have a WordPress woocommerce application, which I want to copy to local server.

But all the links still point to the same server. E.g. when I login it takes me to live website as the action target is sth like : www.example.com/wp-login.php.

How to change all links to point to local servers so that I can develop locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same with WP CLONE Plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has absolute links inside its database, i.e. http://yoursite.org. To make site functional on another domain or localserver you have to change all links inside database. Any manual manipulation with database may corrupt it.

The robust way to move your site is usage of [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use WP All in One plugin, you export whole wordpress and woocommerce, and only thing you need to change when you set it to localhost are permalinks